# Disable pagination in Yii2 gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2

How to disable pagination in Yii2 GridView? I am not using any kartik gridview. I am using the default Yii2 Gridview.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try setting pagination (in your controller) to false, like this:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query'      => SomeModelClass::find(),
    'pagination' => false,
]);
```

Comment: Edited as you suggested. Have a nice one!

Comment: I had problems with some code that was expecting pagination to have pageSize element, so I used `'pagination' => ['pageSize' => 0]`.

Comment: Are you sure about it,  Do you meant to set the pagination in Search Model

Answer (score 2):

1) If you have a limited number of models, use ArrayDataProvider and get all models, instead of ActiveDataProvider.

2) You can specify it in the view, the `layout` property of the GridView can be set to `{summary}{items}`. The default one includes `{pager}` too.